# I want to send argv from python without using command line prompt

Tags: python, arguments

I need to invoke visualstudio .exe file and also send a location on my computer as an argument to it from my python script. 
NOTE: I know its easy doing it via command prompt, tried it and works fine. But I need to do it via scripts only.

P.S: Python Beginner.

Here is my code:

```
browse.filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=[("All files", "*")])
Path_Name = browse.filename
src_files = os.listdir(Path_Name)
Argument = Path_Name + '/' + src_files[x]
print (Argument)
subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/Kailash/Documents/Visual_Studio_2015/Projects/Python_Test/Debug/Python_Test.exe Argument")
```

The last line open the location and executes the Python_Test.exe successfully but sends the argument as "Argument" only. But I need this to send Path_Name + '/' + src_files[x] which is actually a location on my computer.

I believe am missing something really small.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Of course it does not add your variable into the string, it doesn't know you are referring to that variable. You should replace `Argument` with `%s` and then after the end of the string `% Argument`. There are nicer ways to pass arguments to subprocess but this should work. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Python) for a brief explanation of string interpolation in python.

Comment: Knew I was missing something basic. Life of a beginner in a programming language.. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've included `Argument` as part of the string. Instead do

`subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/Kailash/Documents/Visual_Studio_2015/Projects/Python_Test/Debug/Python_Test.exe " + Argument)`

BTW, normally you would make your variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you. I will remember the lowercase!